# CORS not working on AWS Lambda (expressAppFromMiddleware)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, graphql, apollo-server

this is my index.js backend on AWS Lambda
I alredy tried CORS every sigle way we know but its still not work. T.T
may I need to setting  something in AWS first?

```js
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-lambda')
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const jwt = require('express-jwt');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const schema = require('./graphql');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const path = "/graphql";

const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: ({ event, context }) => ({
        headers: event.headers,
        functionName: context.functionName,
        event,
        context,
    })
});
exports.handler = server.createHandler({
    expressGetMiddlewareOptions: {
        cors: {
            origin: "http://localhost:3000",
            credentials: true,
        }
    },
    expressAppFromMiddleware(middleware) {
        const app = express();

        const mongodb_uri = "mongodb+srv://###############################################"
        mongoose.Promise = Promise;
        mongoose.connect(mongodb_uri, {
            dbName: "myDB",
            promiseLibrary: Promise,
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
        });

        app.use(cookieParser());
        app.use(express.json());
        app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
        app.use(
            cors({
                origin: "http://localhost:3000",
                credentials: true,
            })
        );
});
```

when I call backend from http://localhost:3000 (frontend)
so we get error

```
Access to fetch at 'https://####################################' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.


createHttpLink.ts:145 POST https://#################################### net::ERR_FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HI, 

      const graphqlHandler = server.createHandler({
            expressGetMiddlewareOptions: {
              cors: {
                origin: process.env.HOST,
                credentials: true
              }
            }
          });

actually does work, You can debug by enabling logs to the lambda and you can see the execution results in

 - API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_<API_Gateway>/<Stage>
From here, you will be able to confirm if the api is being executed or not. 
 - You can find the lambda logs in dedicated cloud watch log.
 
Pre-flight call is failing in your case, since you have added 
 - Cors : * and credentials: inclue.
This wont work, I would suggest you to add a specific host name so that, include option of credentials will work
```